# Files without extensions in listbox

Tags: c#

1.) How I can remove file extension (".txt")?
2.) Why when I click somewhere to listbox window so all items are replicated???

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Folder");
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: 2) because you don’t clear the listbox?

Answer (score 2):

```
listBox.Items.Clear(); // to clear current listbox items
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
}
```

Comment: Your second proposal is going to return some pretty strange results if he ever starts searching for .cs or .html files.

Comment: @DourHighArch if you see I had commented that this one works because search pattern is "*.txt", but let me edit and make it more clear.

Comment: The `System.IO.Path` class has static methods that allow you to play filename games

Comment: @Flydog57 If you look at my answer I have used `System.Io.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`

Comment: I would just remove that second part.  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension is a function though, so you need to fix that.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes got drawn to the "causing trouble" code that you have since removed.

Comment: And why when I click somewhere to listbox window so all items are replicated like next new items???

Comment: @JD_1609 the code is in indexchanged event of list box, so whern its index is changed (selected index) changes it loads the new items. so 1. you should check that new index is not -1 (nothing is slected) because it will throw an exception and return if it is -1 2.clear listbox items first thing after that